# Integration testing a node site with grunt and jasmine

Tags: gruntjs, jasmine

I'm running a node app on `localhost:1337`

How can I use Grunt.js and Jasmine to test the client-side?

The `grunt-contrib-jasmine` requires `src` files, but I don't want to test static .js fils, I want to test the ones included on the page of my app dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using template for that? It is commonly a bad idea to test the client code with the server code running, unless you want to do integration testing. If you want to test specific javascript generated on the fly by your server, I would recommend mocking them so that you are not tightly couple with your server.

Are you using node? If so, there's a great node module called jasmine-node that enable jasmine dialect on the server side. Check it out: https://github.com/mhevery/jasmine-node